# Как автоматически подставлять нужный путь для сохранения файлов bash

Tags: linux, bash

Суть моей задачи в следующем:
Я создал функцию которая при запуске создает новую директорию с названием сегодняшней даты (/home/sm/2021-11-25)

```
function new_dir {
mkdir -p $(date +%Y-%m-%d)
}
```

Мне необходимо в функции nomer_1 автоматически добавлять/подставлять путь из функции new_dir где будут создаваться файлы и откуда будет считываться нужная информация, на данный момент я вручную прописывал нужные пути.

```
function nomer_1 {
for i in {1..100};    #создаем файлы
do echo  $(( $RANDOM % 8999 + 1000 )) > /home/sm/2021-11-25/File$i; done
cat /home/sm/2021-11-25/* | while read y  #просмотр содержимого файлов из папки
do
echo "$y" >> /home/sm/2021-11-25/s
done
}
echo "$y"
```

Прошу подсказать как это сделать ?

Comment: Надо не подставлять путь из `new_dir`, а сначала его генерировать и потом передавать в `new_dir` и `nomer_1`.

Comment: так я это и сделал.  в функции new_dir я создал новую директорию. Например при запуске сегодня у меня появилась новая директория 2021-12-10 (Полный путь к ней  /home/sm/2021-12-10 )

Comment: Ну так путь к ней сейчас генерируется внутри `new_dir` а надо генерировать снаружи и передавать

Comment: честно говоря не понятно, какая разница папка та создалась по факту

Comment: Разница в том, что путь в `nomer_1` на надо будет хардкодить

Comment: так как это сделать можете привести пример

Comment: ¿Т.е. вопрос сводится к тому, как передать аргументы в функцию?

Comment: `$ fu(){ echo "первый аргумент функции: $1"; }; fu 12345`

Answer (score 0):

Передавать ничего не нужно - теряется весь смысл функции, ведь передать можно напрямую в mkdir. А вот создать переменную имеет смысл.

```
function new_dir {
  YMD=$(pwd)/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
  mkdir -p $YMD
}

function nomer_1 {
  ...
  cat $YMD/* ...
  ...
}
```